# How safe/protect Azure service principal secret

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-keyvault

My deploy task using PowerShell script, which use Service Principal for connection to Azure KeyVault for pull secret. Secret (password) store in PowerShell script's code as plain text. Maybe there is another solution how to minimize token viewing.

And also i use powershell inline mode (not separate script) with Azure DevOps Secret Variable in deploy task, but this solution difficult to support (script has several different operations, so you have to keep many versions of the script).

Script is store in Git repository, anyone who has access to it will be able to see the secret and gain access to other keys. Perhaps I don't understand this concept correctly, but if keys cannot be stored in the code, then what should I do?

Comment: Full agree with user3211888`s answer. You could use the variable groups and set the value as secret, so that you could keep many versions of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I devops you can use variable groups and define that the variables is pulled directly from a selected keyvault (if the service principal you have selected have read/list access to the KV) [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault).

This means that you can define all secrets in keyvault, and they would be pulled before any tasks happens in your yaml. To be able to use them in the script you can define them as a env variable or parameter to your script and just reference $env:variable or just $variable, instead of having the secret hardcoded in your script.

Comment: If I correct understood, you recommend use secret variable from variable groups, and transfer in plain text secret value to the powershell script task by script argument

Comment: yes, all of the secrets are handled as system.string in powershell, and there is really nothing you can do to stop it. even if you would have manually connected to a KV and gotten the secret yourselves, it would still be a system.string when you read it.